# Trouble with ActionResult function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to implement the following ActionResult function but I have an error:

Error    1    'System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet' does not contain a definition for 'Find' and no extension method 'Find' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    C:\Users\SDC\Documents\Adv Web\U0858987_PennineTheatre_Component_2\U0858987_PennineTheatre_Component_2\Controllers\ShowController.cs    37    35    U0858987_PennineTheatre_Component_2

Can anyone please help with correcting this error?

```
 // DETAILS
    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        Show shows = db.Shows.Find(id);
        //var show = db.Shows.Find(id);
        return View(shows);
    }
```

Comment: What is it exactly that you do not understand about the error message? You have an [`ObjectSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412719.aspx), and it does not have a method `Find`.

Comment: I have used the Find before in what I thought was the same context so I do not understand what is wrong?

Comment: I guess that it was not actually the same context after all.

Comment: I am new to MVC and used the approach of index() to return a list, in this case genres, then a browse() to return the shows within that genre, the then the details() to return the details of selected show, its worked before but not sure how to fix it. Only difference is this time database was built in visual studio as .mdf and last time used .sdf

Comment: The problem is there is no such method called Find on sn ObjectSet<T>

Comment: // RETREIVE THE INDIVIDUAL DETAILS SHOWS
        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            //Show shows = db.Shows.Find(id);
            var show = from s in db.Show.Where(id == Show.id) select s;

            return View(show);
        } This is my latest attempt to solve my problem but has not worked anyone??

Answer (score 0):

`db.Shows` is an [`ObjectSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412719.aspx) which has no `Find` method, but there are lots of other methods that can be used instead (including LINQ). So you can have:

```
// don't forget to use the System.Linq namespace
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    var show = db.Shows.Single(s.Id == id);
}
```